# What is the source of the fear in the Hallow spell's extra Fear effect?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, conditions, fear

When using the "Fear" extra effect of the [*hallow*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/hallow) spell, the spell says that affected creatures are frightened whilst in the spell's area.

With regards to the frightened condition: is the source of fear the point at which *hallow* was cast, or the whole area?

This matters for how it interacts with both parts of the frightened condition:

1. If the source of fear is the point at which the spell is cast, then
   affected creatures can move away from it and there might be ways to
   break line of sight within the hallowed area itself.
2. If the source of the fear is the whole area, being inside the area
   means that the source of fear is in all directions from the affected
   creature. This would mean that the creature could not willingly move
   in any direction, as all directions would be closer to the source of
   fear.

   Alternatively, you could interpret it as you are always at the source of fear so you could freely move, as moving in any direction could not put you closer to the source of fear than you already are.

   In addition to the movement restriction/non-restriction (depending on your interpretation), the whole area being the source of fear would mean that you are always subject to the effect of being in line of sight of your source of fear whilst in the area.

What is the correct interpretation?

Comment: Edit was for format.  Nice question, and Welcome to RPGSE.  :)  The [tour] and the [help] are available as guides for how to get the most out of an SE Q&A site.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

## RAW: Unclear

As written, the [Hallow](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/hallow) spell does not specify any of this, as you noted. I can't find any mention of Hallow in the [Sage Advice Compendium](https://media.wizards.com/2019/dnd/downloads/SA-Compendium.pdf) or the [PHB Errata](http://media.wizards.com/2018/dnd/downloads/PH-Errata.pdf), and I couldn't find any unofficial tweets by Jeremy Crawford referencing this use of Hallow either, so we have little to go on as for the designer intent.

## Recommended: Both

If the Frightened condition inflicted by the area is supposed to have any effect, then it doesn't really do us any good to *only* look at either the area or the point of origin - as you note, both lead to some absurd results that kind of defeat the point of using the option in the first place.

I'd *recommend* treating the "source" of the fear as the entire area for the purposes of determining if you can "see" it, and as the origin of the area for the purposes of moving closer to it. That might feel slightly inconsistent, but it leads to much more sensible results - you can move *out* of the area if you're in it, but not closer into it. You're also continuously affected by the disadvantage imposed by the frightened condition as long as you're in the area.

I can't prove that this is the design intent; it is merely how I'd expect an effect like this to work.

Answer (score 2):

### The source of the fear is the whole area in which the spell was cast.

I know Cubic already pointed out that RAW is unclear, but I'm going to attempt to explain why this is the most logical interpretation.

First of all, this is working from the assumption that a ***source*** is "whatever causes a given effect to manifest". Since the trigger for all of the effects is ***being in the area*** this must also be the source of the effect. The point at which the spell was cast was simply to determine the centre of the circle the spell affects, but the area itself is what causes the creature within it to become frightened.

So to address point 2, since that is what I'm asserting the source to be:

You're right that being inside the area means that every direction leads towards the source, but keep in mind that creatures rarely move arbitrarily; they are generally moving towards a *destination* (be that an enemy to attack, a vantage point to scout, or down an escape route as they flee). Rather than saying ***this creature can't move because it's surrounded by the source of its fear*** I think it's more accurate to say ***this creature will head towards the closest destination point outside the spell's area***. This means that when it moves, it's still moving away from the source of its fear, even if it doesn't have enough movement to leave the area yet.

Functionally, this results in pretty much identical behaviour to Cubic's recommendation, since the closest exit from the part of the area the creature is in will always end up being the direction leading away from the centre (this also covers an edge case with using the origin as the source meaning the creature would stop moving if the other directions are blocked somehow; considering destinations rather than individual moves means they could move towards the origin if it's the only way to go to get out of the area due to walls, people blocking the way etc)

Comment: "this creature will head towards the closest destination point outside the spell's area"
The reason I don't like this interpretation is because this is *not* what the Frightened condition says - it doesn't force you to move anywhere, it just prevents motion in certain directions, specifically "The creature can’t willingly move closer to the source of its fear", if the entire area is equally the source then you're either always or never moving closer to the source as the original question pointed out.

Comment: I should have specified that this only applies *if the creature moves*; it could also just not move.

Comment: Imagine I'm in a room that has a blue square painted on the floor. If I move to the edge of the square heading towards the doorway, I'm still inside the square but I was moving away from it.

Comment: @Cubic If the entire area is the source of the fear, and you're inside the area, you're right on top of the source of your fear (i.e. distance to source = 0). Moving within the area wouldn't be moving any closer, because you **can't** get any closer than zero, but you also wouldn't be moving *away* until you leave the area.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist My argument here is that rather than figuring the distance between the source and the affected creature, what we should be considering is the distance between the source and where the creature is trying to go.

Comment: @JohnClifford To figure out whether they're moving closer, you need to work out both. They are moving closer to the source if *distance between source and intended destination* is less than *distance between source and current location*. However, if the entire area is the source, *distance between source and intended destination* (when within the area) is zero **and** *distance between source and current location* is zero; zero is not **less than** zero, so they aren't moving closer.

Comment: I know, that's why I'm saying that they would have to try moving to somewhere outside the area to be able to move.

Comment: @JohnClifford From my perspective, no point within the area is any closer to the source of their fear than any other point, so they would have free movement. That is probably not the intended result of the spell, because it seems like it would make the frightened effect weaker, but it's the only explanation that makes sense to me with the way the rules are written.

Comment: If the entire area is the source of the fear and being inside the area imply that the distance target-source = 0ft, how could going from 0ft away to 0ft away be considered moving closer ? Also, the term "surrounded" feel like each case is considered as an independent source of fear (in this case, I would agree that moving inside the area = moving closer to a source)

Comment: @AnthonyGrist Either we measure distance to the closest point (which is zero, and so the creature can move without restriction in the area), or we do some kind of integration of the distance to every point of the area (in which case the creature just can't move closer to the center). It's not clear how to handle this; the Frightened condition kind of assumes the "source of the fear" is a single point.

Comment: I think this is a really bizarre edge case where to resolve it we need to consider the *intent* of the spell, which is to block off an area from a certain set of creatures. It's pretty clear that mechanically what should happen is that if the creature enters the area they become scared and try to get out of it.

Answer (score 0):

## Frightened of the area

From the spell description, the targets should be frightened by the area since this effect is bound to it and not to its origin :

> Second, you can bind an extra effect to the *area*.

## What does it implies

If the entire area effectively frightening the targets, it implies that :

- While the target is in the area (per the spell), *and the area is within line of sight* (per the condition), they have disadvantage on ability checks and attack rolls.

  - As [John Clifford](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/154711/what-is-the-source-of-the-fear-in-the-hallow-spells-extra-fear-effect/154747?noredirect=1#comment403332_154747) said in a comment, closing your eyes/being blind doesn't change line of sight since its defined as :

> to precisely determine... line of sight..., pick a corner of one space and trace an imaginary line from that corner to any part of another space. If at least one such line doesn't pass through or touch an object or effect that blocks vision... then there is line of sight.

- The creature can't willingly move closer to the area. Luckily for them, they can't be any closer : since they are inside the space of the area, the distance between the target and the area (not its source) is effectively 0. Moving in the area doesn't make the target move closer than 0ft away so they should be able to do it.

Comment: @JohnClifford Oops, corrected. I'm not really surprised though : it didn't worked either against the monster under my bed.

Answer (score -1):

You assume the victims are afraid *of some source*, but nothing in the spell says that. It simply makes the victims afraid. Since they feeling goes away when they leave the area, however, this is effectively the same as being afraid of the area and everything within.

Answer (score -1):

## The area is the source of the fear.

From the spell description:

> Second, you can **bind an extra effect** to **the area**. Choose the effect from the following list, or choose an effect offered by the DM. Some of these effects **apply to creatures in the area**...

Emphasis mine. This clearly states that the *whole* area is the source of the effect chosen, not its point of origin.

### The effect of the Fear option therefore does not restrict the movement of an affected creature.

The frightened condition prevents a creature from moving *closer* to the source of the condition. However, when the creature is *inside* the area—which is the only time it is affected—the source is 0 ft away from it. Therefore, an affected creature can move freely.

Comment: (1/2) Good job showing that the entire area is the source of the fear - but it doesn't seem like the intent for it to have no affect on movement once inside.  Rather, if the point of _hallow_ is to protect it, the fear effect should prevent one from moving toward it (if outside) or deeper within it (if inside).

Comment: (2/2)  If you were programming this, for example, you might measure the distance from the affected creature's square to every other square in the area of effect, and then take the sum of all of those distances.  Movement would be prohibited if the sum of all the distances would decrease, but permitted if the sum of all the distances increased - that is, if in a net sense you were moving farther away from the area.

Comment: (1/2) While I think that would be an interesting way of conceiving a distance which permits a notion of getting 'closer' to something which you are inside, I don't think that it's appropriate to apply it to this situation discussing D&D 5e game rules (which, I'm fairly sure, doesn't have any kind of system in it).

Comment: (2/2) Regarding your first point, I believe that other parts of the spell are intended to do the 'protecting' in the sense of *keeping creatures out* (in particular, the primary effect of the spell): other negative effects (such as the Energy Vulnerability effect) also have no effect on physically prevening creatures from entering (nor moving further into) the area. Note that the frightened condition has other effects which would be beneficial to keeping affected creatures at bay—again, similarly to the Energy Vulnerability effect.

Comment: (3/2) Note that this is not a question on intent, but effect: while I also believe that the intent is not to have this particular instance of the frightened condition restrict movement, the question asks what the *correct* interpretation is (as opposed to the intended interpretation), and so that's what I'm trying to answer.